# Display unique object names and a count of their occurences

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following sample objects:

```
Object {color: green, total: 0}
Object {color: red, total: 0}
Object {color: blue, total: 0}
Object {color: blue, total: 0}
Object {color: green, total: 0}
```

How do I efficiently loop through and display unique color names with total occurrences?

Desired output:

```
green: 2
red: 1
blue: 2
```

Actual output:

```
green: 1
red: 1
blue: 1
```

I am looping through the matrix, and check if the color name exists in the array... if not, then it will be added, and the actual `<span>` will be added to $spans. If the name already exists in the array, I want to increment `total` of that matrix entry so keep track of its occurences

```
 var colorNames = [];
            for (var row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
                for (var col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
                    if (matrixPaths[row][col] == 1) {                           
                        if($.inArray(matrix[row][col].data('color'), colorNames) == -1) {
                            matrix[row][col].data()['total'] += 1;
                            colorNames.push(matrix[row][col].data('color'));
                            $spans.push(matrix[row][col]);
                        }
                        else { 
                            matrix[row][col].data()['total'] += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }           
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be unnecessarily complicated. If I have understood the question correctly, you could use an object:

```
var count = {}, clr;

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) 
{
    clr = colors[i].color;
    if ( count.hasOwnProperty(clr) ) 
       count[clr] += 1;
    else 
       count[clr] = 1;
}
```

Where `colors` is an array of objects.

Comment: This is so awesome. I didn't know you could just create a property for a key on the fly like that `count[clr]`